# run a command, send output to mail with stderror colored

Tags: command-line, email, colors, stdout

I have a script that writes to the STDOUT and STDERR. I can pipe the script to mail so it sends me an email of the output.

What I want to do now is have the STDERR of the output colored such that the e-mail message is colored. I suspect I'll have to use some kind of HTML for this but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Use one of the options in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to post process the merged output after the pipe.

A coloring of the streams could be achieved be a wrapping program around the script that also controls their merging. E.g., a line based merging, and then duly decorate the STDERR lines prior to emitting them. It requires an amount of coding.